# Graphical user interface for FormFlow in BotFramework

Tags: c#, botframework

We can employ form flow to enable user interactions with the bot in a flow of prompts. [Here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html) is a great example for doing this for a simple "Order a sandwich" task. I want to know instead of command line prompts can I use real graphical interfaces? And instead of hard-coding the options can I pull the fields from a database or from some external resources through API calls?

Comment: What do you mean by GUI?  Buttons?

Comment: Button text boxes. Buttons are already available. But text boxes, radio buttons and other input elements from Windows forms.

Answer (score 0):

None of the messenger channels (i.e. Facebook / Skype / Slack) support complex GUI elements yet (i.e. radio buttons, combo boxes, etc).

Comment: OK, but at-least can we pull enum fields dynamically from a database?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [the `DynamicField` elements](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html#dynamicFields), you can indeed populate the options from anywhere you like (including a database if you so wish):

```
.Field(new FieldReflector<BugReport>(nameof(Product))
                        .SetType(null)
                        .SetDefine((state, field) =>
                        {
                            foreach (var prod in GetProducts())
                                field
                                    .AddDescription(prod, prod)
                                    .AddTerms(prod, prod);

                            return Task.FromResult(true);
                        }))
```

Where `GetProducts` returns you a list of products - this could be from a DB, etc.

Sample taken from [Dynamic FormFlow Forms in Bot Builder](http://mayoster.blogspot.co.uk/2016/05/dynamic-formflow-forms-in-bot-builder.html).